# Removing duplicates by max date

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table in my MySQL database that I need to remove the duplicates from.

My table looks something like this:

```
unique_id    value    frequency    value_type    publication_date
1             6.5     1            2             2014-12-31
2             7.5     3            5             2014-06-04
3             6.5     1            2             2015-07-13
4             8.0     4            3             2010-12-31
```

Rows 1 and 3 are duplicates except for the publication_date. I need to remove these duplicates but keep the row with the max publication date so for this example I would want to remove row 1 and keep row 3.

So far I've tried this but it's giving me too many results on my test table:

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(SELECT MAX(publication_date) AS most_recent_date
 FROM table_1
 GROUP BY `value`,frequency,value_type
) t1
JOIN table_1 t 
ON t.publication_date = t1.most_recent_date;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN to remove the duplicates as

```
delete t1 from table_1 t1
join table_1 t2 on t1.value = t2.value 
and t1.frequency= t2.frequency 
and t1.value_type = t2.value_type
and t1.unique_id <> t2.unique_id
and t1.publication_date < t2.publication_date ;
```

Comment: I can see the logic behind this but when I run a select version of it I get no results.